# Knowing about page which has called RESTful API

Tags: java, angularjs

How can we know the name of the page or service or state of page which has called RESTful API in java file. Something like `$state.current.name` in AngularJS.

I have created api's in java using `@RequestMapping()`. In this java file I want to know about the name of page that has called this API. As I want to call same api on different pages and want to log different strings according to the page which has requested the API. I am using  `$http.get(api)` in AngularJS to call API.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [referer header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)?

Comment: @Tobías I can't retrieve the complete URL using referer header. As I can only get the ip address and name of project. What I want is the content after #, i.e. state of page.

Comment: Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040304/angular-ui-router-get-the-current-state-from-within-a-view?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) almost a similar question.

Comment: How about setting a cookie with the state name so that it gets included in the request?

Comment: @SudhirOjha, I want the state in the Java file, not in js file.

Comment: @Protozoid, thanks for suggestion. Actually I have already created whole project just for the sake of logs I do not want to change all the functions. Is there any direct function?

Answer (score 0):

We found the most reliable way to achieve knowledge of the current URL/state is to send it as part of the request payload. This gets around issues of HTTP referer header stripping. You already have `$state.current.name`, so adding this to your API-calling JS service function *should* be straightforward.

If you need to add this to every request, one option is to use an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) to add the metadata into every HTTP request which contains JSON.